# Resize height of parent div when relative child div is repositioned

Tags: html, css

Please take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j53qg29b/8/).

What I intend to achieve here is to make the parent div (yellow container) to resize its height according to its content.

One of its child div (blue container) is in `position: relative` and repositioned on `bottom: 30px;`.

However, with this setting, the parent div doesn't seem to adjust and still has a space below the child divs.

Comment: Setting something to `position: absolute` takes the element out of the normal page flow. This is why your yellow `<div>` is not resizing. Try using `position: relative` or otherwise, adjust your yellow div height manually.

Comment: My bad, it's not `position: absolute` but `position: relative` but still the same result

Comment: @ChristopherBennett still trying to figure out how to manually adjust the height. Adding height property on yellow div didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the blue div relative.  and also add `margin-bottom: -30px;` to blue div. Yellow div will adjust with blue.

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 80px;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.main-left {
  width: 55%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

    .main-right {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 30px;
  margin-bottom: -30px;
  width: 45%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header">header</div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="main-left">
      main left
    </div>
    <div class="main-right">
      <p>main</p>
      <p>right</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: But, blue div is no longer repositioned higher than the yellow div

Comment: updated the answer margin-bottom: -30px; was the solution putted back in the bottom:30px

Comment: No problem :) glad to be a help.